# How to create data CD in xUbuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, cd

Xfburn shown error message when proceeding with burn:

> Write not implemented

... or something like that. How to implement it? Is this a bug?

Comment: I would try with **k3b** or **Brasero**. You may also need some background tools, that I think you get when installing the package `ubuntu-restricted-extras` or in your case maybe `xubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked on 18.04. If it is "not implemented" then why is it part of the 20.04 distro.  apt install is unable to locate any  of -restricted, but my setup does show Software restricted...

Comment: I have installed the [meta package] `ubuntu-restricted-extras` in my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, so I know that it exists. But I checked, and there is no `xubuntu-restricted-extras` in 20.04 LTS, so we are both 'half right' and 'half wrong'. (I *think* that `ubuntu-restricted-extras` can be installed in Xubuntu too, but have not done it.) I have never used Xfburn, and I have not burned any DVD in 20.04 LTS. Instead I'm using USB pendrives, external SSDs, memory cards, LAN and the internet nowadays. But I am rather sure that I have burned some CDs and DVDs in 18.04 LTS using k3b.

Comment: I understand, right. I did burn CDs, DVDs in 18.04, and I can still burn them if I need to with my other, older desktop (highly customized, bastardized Fedora-3). Yet, I still don't understand, why 20.04 includes Xfburn if it does not work. But that's OK, open source, open for improvements.